# RF signal detection vs mixer and amplifier noise

Tags: amplifier, rf, noise, signal, mixer

What I am trying to do is some sort of amateur radio. But not exactly a radio, for now I will just detect the presence of a signal. I will synthesize an RF signal with a frequency synthesizer, transmit it and receive it and down-convert it using a down-converter mixer. For the LO I will be using another frequency synthesizer. Then I will filter the IF, amplify it, rectify it into a DC signal, then power up a buzzer with it and that will be the detection, that yes, signal received.

My main problem here is that there is noise in mixer and amplifier as far as I have understood. That would mean, there will be voltage coming up to the buzzer due to noise even when there is no signal.

I am thinking of using mainly two mixer ICs at different times of my experiment. One is AD608 from Analog Devices and another is MAX2682 from Maxim Integrated. The problem arose mainly when I was reading datasheet of AD608. This mixer has a logarithmic limiting amplifier with it. The IF is amplified and also limited by it in 400 mV peak to peak (for driving the buzzer I will have to further amplify it). Then it says, "The limiter output impedance is 200 Ω, and the  limiter output drive is ± 200 mV (400 mV p-p) into a 5 kΩ load. In the absence of an input signal, the limiter output limits noise fluctuations, producing an output that continues to swing 400 mV p-p, but with random zero crossings."

Now my question is, if it continues to swing even when there is no input, will the buzzer keep ringing even when there is no input? What can I do to get over this problem? How do radio amateurs and other professional devices deal with these problems?

Please also shed light on the matter, what would happen in case there was no limiter. The amplifier has very high gain, 110 db. This causes, as far as I understand, even very weak signals (-95 dbm) to reach the 400 mV level in output. This also means, as per my understanding, that noise too will reach that level. But this would mean a chaotic situation, which a device like this should have been designed to not cause. So what is the matter actually. And what is the significance of "but with random zero crossings" (in the portion from the datasheet I have mentioned).

And if the limiter is absent, then weak signals and noise should stay within a certain limit, while stronger signals would reach a higher peak to peak voltage, so if we can fix a range (probably by using a resistor to attenuate the signal and noise) above which we will make the buzzer start buzzing, we should be able to at least detect signals above a threshold. Say, noise reaches 400 mV peak to peak, but we are also getting signals that reach more than that. So if we make the buzzer respond to signals only above 400 mV p-p, then we should be able to get over the noise problem. Would it be so?

I am not sure also, how frequent is noise? Is it always there, or keeps coming and going? And as I would be filtering the IF, should the filter reject a lot of noise (that which falls out of the IF range) inherently?

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD608.pdf

https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2680-MAX2682.pdf

Here I have pasted links to datasheets of AD608 and MAX2682 for any assistance in advance.

Any other mixer device suggestion is also welcome (within 500 MHz).

And one thing, I am pretty new to this sector. Hoping to get some insightful response. Thank you.

Comment: Useful search term : squelch circuit

Comment: You can modulate it with a tone and decode the tone to kill noise as well. When you detect the tone open the squelch circuit. You state transmit it, Check the rules of the governing authority in your area/country, They have rules and regulations you must adhere to.

Comment: Thank you @user_1818839 for the squelch term. Sorry for the delayed response.